# What is disposition: enforce in CSP frame-ancestors?

Tags: http, security, content-security-policy, x-frame-options, websecurity

Quoting from [here](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options),

> If a resource is delivered with a policy that includes a directive named frame-ancestors and whose disposition is "enforce", then the `X-Frame-Options` header will be ignored, per HTML’s processing model.

I don't understand the part that mentions 'disposition is "enforce"'. Can't find examples. Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#policy-disposition: 'Each policy has an associated disposition, which is either "enforce" or "report".' This corresponds to Content-Security-Policy and Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only, respectively. If you are using the "Report-Only" version of CSP, X-Frame-Options will not be ignored as you are not enforcing the overriding policy.

Comment: So it's not something that we can specify explicitly, and instead inferred based on whether or not the report-only variant is used. Right?

Is there an official/near-official source for this?

Comment: You specify this by setting the response header name to "Content-Security-Policy" or "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only".